# Reading docx file with R and converting the values to numeric

Tags: r, file, text, r-markdown, docx

I have this docx file ( https://github.com/rhozon/datasets/blob/master/idades.docx?raw=true ) and I want to read this file directly in the link and convert the numbers to numeric.

I´m using `textreadr::read_docx(...` but I believe that here I can find an better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(textreadr)

read_docx("idades.docx") %>% 
  str_split(",") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  str_trim() %>% 
  as.numeric()
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks Paul Smith!

Comment: You are welcome, Rodrigo! And please mark my answer as a correct one.